# How do I add a save feature to a datagridview?

Tags: visual-studio, datagridview, save

Hi i am fairly new to visual studio and I am having some trouble adding a save feature to my program. Basically what my program does is set event reminder for the user (it's like a daily planner but with no notifications). I have got the "add event', "delete", and "update buttons to work on the program and now all I have left is the "save" and "load" key. What I am trying to do is find a way to save the DataGridView so it can be opened back up in the program at a later date using the "load" key. If it would be easier to just remove the "load" and save the info right into the event reminder application, I could go that route but I don't have the first idea how to do that. This is what I have right now for the code in the main form:

Public Class MainForm1

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

    If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "Delete" AndAlso Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow = False Then
        Me.DataGridView1.EndEdit()
        Me.DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex)
    End If

    If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "Column4" AndAlso Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow = False Then
        Dim Update As UpdateWindow
        Update = UpdateWindow
        Update.Show()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub dltBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim dltBtn As dltWindow
    dltBtn = dltWindow
    dltBtn.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Button1 As addBtn
    Button1 = addBtn
    Button1.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub UptBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim UptBtn As UpdateWindow
    UptBtn = UpdateWindow
    UptBtn.Show()
End Sub

Dim thisFilename As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Event reminder.dat"

Private Sub saveBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles saveBtn.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.SaveGridData(DataGridView1, thisFilename)
End Sub

Private Sub BtnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnLoad.Click
    Me.LoadGridData(DataGridView1, thisFilename)
End Sub

Private Sub SaveGridData(ByRef ThisGrid As DataGridView, ByVal thisFilename As String)
    ThisGrid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithoutHeaderText
    ThisGrid.SelectAll()
    IO.File.WriteAllText(thisFilename, ThisGrid.GetClipboardContent().GetText.TrimEnd)
    ThisGrid.ClearSelection()
End Sub

Private Sub LoadGridData(ByRef ThisGrid As DataGridView, ByVal Filename As String)
    ThisGrid.Rows.Clear()
    For Each THisLine In My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Filename).Split(Environment.NewLine)
        ThisGrid.Rows.Add(Split(THisLine, " "))
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

I have gone on the other forums and asked about how to do this and they all said the bind the datagridview to a data table. If that is the route I have to go, how do I go about it? If anyone has some examples or code I could try out I would be much appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I can see in the posted code is between the `LoadGridData` and the `SaveGridData` methods. When the `LoadGridData` method runs, it reads a file where each line is “Split” on spaces “ “. This is fine and if the file is properly “space” delimited it works as expected. So let us assume everything works and the data displays in the grid properly.

Then the user presses the `saveBtn` which calls the `SaveGridData` method. The code appears to “select” all the cells in the `DataGridView` to the clipboard, then proceeds to write the clipboard text to the SAME file name used when loading the grid. This also appears to work as expected.

The problem with this is that when the code copies all the cells of the `DataGridView` to the clipboard then, writes this copied clipboard text; it will use a “Tab” delimiter. The file `Event reminder.dat` which was read in using a “space” delimiter will be overwritten with a “tab” delimiter and not a “space” delimiter. Therefore, then next time the load method is run… it will fail.

If the load and save button are going to read the same file, then they MUST both agree on what character is used as a delimiter. You can use whatever character you want as a delimiter. You can use a “space” as the posted code does, however this limits each type to a string with no spaces. If one of the fields is a home address, chances are good, there will be a space in the string. Using a “space” as a delimiter is not necessarily the best of choices.

A simple solution is available with the current code. Currently if the file `Events reminder.dat` is space delimited and reads in properly to the data grid view, then it should be easy to replace the space delimiter with something else. In this case, since the `SaveGridData` method is delimiting the fields with a “tab” then we simply need to change the load method to “split” on “Tabs” and not “spaces” when reading back the file.

Step 1 – make a copy of `Events reminder.dat`

Step 2 – Run the program, press the load button and make sure all the data is properly loaded into the grid.

Step 3 – If the data is displayed properly in the grid, press the save button. (Updates file with tab delimiters)

Step 4 – Exit the program and make the change below in the `LoadGridData` method.

```
ThisGrid.Rows.Add(Split(THisLine, vbTab))
```

Step 5 – Run the program. Now both the load and write methods agree on what character (Tab) is used as a delimiter.

Lastly, to comment on using a `DataTable` the answer would be yes. `DatagridView`s and `DataTable`s play nicely together. Hope this helps.

You may want to take a [“Tour”](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of Stackoverflow to see how it works.

Comment: I tried saving it and then loading it but it messed up or something because it put Wednesday in the date column and May in the event description column of the datagridview.

Comment: If you are using your posted code in the question to do this, then as I said, The “Save” method saves the file using “tabs” to separate/delimit each column of data. If you try to read this file back using your posted “load” method, it will fail because it is using “spaces” as a separator/delimiter. Therefore, the columns will not match up properly because the two methods use TWO different separators/delimiters for each column. Make the change in the “load” method and use an empty file to start with, add some data, then save the file, then the load method will work properly.